# Should ACF functions the_field() and get_field() be escaped?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Should ACF fields be escaped? Or are they safe to use by just the_field() and get_field() functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Harven said, then you need to escape your own (according to the [Advanced Custom Fields forum](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get_field-the_field-return-escaped-value/) ).

In there, these is a suggestion to add a filter, so you don't need to do it every time:

```
<?php
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
  return esc_attr($value);
} 

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=url', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [esc_attr](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) at your own.